# What is the difference between Item and Element in PHP Array?

Tags: php, arrays

When dealing with PHP arrays, I am confused about items and elements like so:

```
$arr = array('name'=>'John','id'=>'123456');
```

Where `$arr` is an Array and

`'name'=>'John'` is an Array Item.

`'name'=>'John'` is an Array Element.

Is there any difference?... are they all referring to the same thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the same thing. It's like automobile and car

Comment: All arrays in php are basically just dictionaries.

Comment: In my experience, the item, or element, is referring to the value, not the key:value pair.    Just something to keep in mind here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array of `elements` or an array of `items` it's the same the thing

an `item` is an `element`  an `element` is an `item` as well.

Answer (score 1):

As for item and element: they're the same thing. When talking about an item or element, people generally mean both the key and the associated value.

Considering the array in your question:

```
$arr = array('name'=>'John','id'=>'123456');
```

In that array, these are your keys:

1. name
2. id

These are your values:

1. John
2. 123456

Lastly, these are your elements:

- name => John
- id => 123456